# How to add spaces when Concatenating strings

Tags: python

I am trying to get this output:
 2014-07-26 02:12:18: Houston Texas

When I try to do the assignment using:

```
current_time = '2014-07-26 02:12:18:'
my_city = 'Houston'
my_state = 'Texas'
log_entry = current_time + my_city +  my_state
print(log_entry)
```

I am getting this output:
2014-07-26 02:12:18:HoustonTexas

How do I get the spaces between the :, Houston, and Texas

Comment: You could do `log_entry = " ".join([current_time, my_city, my_state])`

Comment: Or `log_entry = current_time +" "+ my_city +" "+  my_state

Comment: Use string formatting: `f"{current_time} {my_city} {my_state}"`

Answer (score 0):

Work them in as string literals in your concatenation:

```
current_time = '2014-07-26 02:12:18:'
my_city = 'Houston'
my_state = 'Texas'
log_entry = current_time + ' ' + my_city + ' ' + my_state
print(log_entry)
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/MerryPaleRuntimelibrary)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them explicitly `thing + " " + otherthing`. Or you could use the `" ".join` method above if you know how to get your variables into a list.